# ActiveAdmin strips off content inside curly braces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a model which has a template string to be parsed by liquid later, which is stored in the database but the edit, show and index of ActiveAdmin doesn't show those fields.

**Code**:

```
irb(main):050:0> q = Question.find(4)
  Question Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
=> #<Question id: 4, question_text: "How happy are you working at {{company_name}}?">
```

question.rb

```
class Question < ApplicationRecord
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "questions", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "question_text"
end
```

**Display in ActiveAdmin**

[image: ActiveAdmin screenshot]

I tried adding raw(question_text) as well, it didn't work. How do I show the variable along with curly braces? ie - I want to see {{company_name}} inside ActiveAdmin.

Comment: Sorry - just added more details.

Comment: can you share the active admin `questions.rb` file.

Comment: @PardeepSaini added

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the column details.

```
clumn "Question Text" do |question| 
  company = Company.find_by_name('abc')
  question.question_text.sub! '{{company_name}}', company.name
end
```

**update**

```
clumn "Question Text" do |question| 
  "#{question.question_text}"
end
```

Comment: I don't want the variable to be substituted, I want ActiveAdmin to literally show {{company_name}}